# DevDemon Subscription + EE3 buggy

Tags: devdemon, ee3, devdemon-subscriptions

{!-- rant --}

I don't seem to get much in the way of support via DevDemon support request (even though I'm still within the 60-day purchase window). I've ran into multiple random bugs with the recently released EE3 version, 
two-weeks on, still waiting for support to get back.

I've got some issues, however, that I can't wait on any longer, so hoping the community can provide a helping hand!

{!-- /rant --}

It seems there is a JS error when attempting to batch delete vouchers (anything more than 5 at a time).

Also, with that, is there a way to allow a voucher to be used by multiple users as apposed to one-off?

Any help on this appreciated!!

Comment: Did you ever get anything resolved regarding this? I'm using this plugin and having odd issues as well.

Comment: Nope, nothing. Support is non-existent. Also, just found out some other issues. Namely: Stripe was not updated to use TLS 1.2, so that was a nice surprise when I turned on "Live" mode. After fixing that myself, I found out the CRON job doesn't work, when hitting the action url no subs are renewed? Isn't that the point of this thing?